# Problem with composer after trying to install a private repository in magento 2

Tags: composer-php, magento2

Please, I need some help.

I tried to install a private repository into magento 2 and after that all the times I try to install (or remove) another thing through composer, they start that private installation again, look:

/composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Package operations: 4 installs, 0 updates, 0 removals

- Installing tcesarpinho/php-sigep-fpdf (0.0.1): Downloading (failed)    Failed to download tcesarpinho/php-sigep-fpdf from dist: The "https://api.github.com/repos/tcesarpinho/php-sigep-fpdf/zipball/3df470f14e861fd7f9b10232364a9444b2fc736b" file could not be downloaded (HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found)
  Now trying to download from source
- Installing tcesarpinho/php-sigep-fpdf (0.0.1): Cloning failed using an ssh key for authentication, enter your GitHub credentials to access private repos
  Head to https://github.com/settings/tokens/new?scopes=repo&description=Composer+on+us124-cp.valueserver.com.br+2020-08-11+2353
  to retrieve a token. It will be stored in "/home/basilioa/public_html/auth.json" for future use by Composer.
  Token (hidden): Killed

What can I do?

Comment: What have you tried so far to resolve this issue? Like: what about the hint provided in the error message, does it work?

Comment: update composer, clear cache, delete the repo folder.. and nothing worked

Comment: Just to clarify: have you tried what the error message tells you? Like: store an access token at some file?